# How to define an empty select case statement in vbscript

Tags: select, vbscript

If I have the following select cases:

```
Select Case var
    Case 1
        doA()
    Case 2
        doB()
    Case 3
        'empty
End select
```

What impact does this empty select case have? Is there an official/legit way to define an empty select case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you omit that case entirely?

```
Select Case var
    Case 1
        doA()
    Case 2
        doB()
End select
```

Comment: You may have a `Case Else` (although not stipulated in the example), where the Else action has an action that is other that doing nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Having an empty Case (marked by a suitable comment) is the correct way to deal with cases like:

```
Select Case DayOfWeek
  Case Sat
    doSaturday
  Case Sun
    ' nothing to do for sundays
  Case Else
    doWorkingDay
End Select
```

Here, omitting the Sun Case would be an error.